# Multilabel binarizer - getting the inverse transform

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, svm

I am stuck on using the Multilabel binarizer and One-vs-all classifier in scikit-learn . My challenge is once I obtain the predictions, 
to obtain the original labels. (I trained and pickled the one-vs-rest classifier and vectorizer separately)

```
_labels = load_labels()
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
mlb.fit_transform(_labels)
print mlb.classes_ # this prints the binarized labels

_clf,_vect = load_pickle('./pickles')

for q in queries:
    #query vector q
    X = vect.transform([q])            
    res = clf.predict_proba(X)
    print res #[[ 0.00164113  0.00706595  0.00683465 .... 0.00837984]]

    #this is where I am stuck on what to pass into the inverse_transform to obtain
    preds = mlb.inverse_transform(??)
    print preds
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: `inverse_transform` will take your labels  and transform them back to the classes with the encoding. so the output of the `inverse_transform` is the input to the `transform`. [MultilabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html)

Comment: @sharatpc, sorry I am a bit confused since my model is trained and pickled earlier, I am re-reading the labels from a csv and `fit_transform` it, what is my input to  the `inverse_transform`?

Comment: output of `mlb.fit_transform(_labels)` will be the input

Comment: Thank you! that worked. thanks so much! pls post as an anwer so I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output of `mlb.fit_transform(_labels)` will be the input to the `inverse_transform`.

More on it is here: [Multilabel Binarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html)

Comment: Hey! So I didn't get it when you say the solution should be :  mlb.inverse_transform(mlb.fit_transform(_labels)). Don't you want the predicted values (res in this case) to be inverse transformed? i.e. -mlb.inverse_transform(mlb.fit_transform(res))? In which case, my predicted value is coming to be a floating number which cannot be inverse transformed, what do we do in that case??